# Merging duplicated rows in sql table

Tags: sql-server

```
FirstDate   LastDate    BaseCUR ConvertedCUR    RATE    
20070501    20070531    USD........EUR.................1.369748 
20070601    20070615    USD........EUR.................1.354772 
20070616    20070702    USD........EUR.................1.354772 
20070703    20070727    USD........EUR.................1.343621 
20070728    20070731    USD........EUR.................1.343621 
20070801    20070831    USD........EUR.................1.376050 
20070901    20071002    USD........EUR.................1.369748
```

Here is sample of my database, my task is to merge the `'FirstDate'` and `'LastDate'` of the following row(s) with the same `'RATE'` into a single row.

I've tried to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to group those duplicate `'RATE'` but it also group those rows which are not adjacent to others, so yet I can't merge all of them.

Is it possible for implementing this query without using any if-else or while-loop?

The result must look like:

```
FirstDate   LastDate    BaseCUR ConvertedCUR  RATE  
20070501    20070531    USD........EUR........1.369748  
20070601    20070702    USD........EUR........1.354772<<< the dates are merged  
20070703    20070731    USD........EUR........1.343621<<< the dates are merged  
20070801    20070831    USD........EUR........1.376050  
20070901    20071002    USD........EUR........1.369748
```

Any solutions or directions would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: hmmm.., i cannot understand your specification for MERGE. please elaborate.

Comment: What is your query? And what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(FirstDate) AS FirstDate, MAX(LastDate) AS LastDate,
       BaseCUR, ConvertedCUR, RATE
FROM (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstDate)  -
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RATE ORDER BY FirstDate) AS rnk
FROM mytable ) t
GROUP BY BaseCUR, ConvertedCUR, RATE, rnk
ORDER BY FirstDate
```

`GROUP BY RATE, rnk` identifies islands of successive `RATE` values. Using `MIN`, `MAX` functions we can calculate the starting and ending dates of each of those islands.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25524/2)

Comment: I think the OP wants a DML query. That makes 2 of us who misunderstand the unclear question. :)

Comment: @tjeloep Perhaps you have right. I tried addressing the following problem in my answer: *I've tried to use ROW_NUMBER() to group those duplicate 'RATE' but it also group those rows which are not adjacent to others, so yet I can't merge all of them*

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this in two steps.   Here is pseudo code for the approach I would take:

1. UPDATE the table, setting FirstDate=MIN(FirstDate) and LastDate=MAX(LastDate) and grouping by all the other columns.
2. Use ROW_NUMBER to eliminate all duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing MERGE will be get the earliest FirsDate and the latest LastDate for the same RATE, BaseCUR and ConvertedCUR.
If that is the case:

SELECT MIN (FirstDate), MAX (LastDate), BaseCUR, ConvertedCUR, RATE FROM YourTable GROUP BY BaseCUR, ConvertedCUR, RATE;

P.S. Please excuse the format, I'm using mobile version on a going jetty.

Comment: Ah.., you want to UPDATE the table. Please ignore my answer then. ...OR, you can INSERT my query INTO a temporary table, DELETE all data from the original table and finally INSERT data from the temporary table INTO the original table. Good luck!